# TEXTIMAGE_ON error en SQL

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[bosh] (
    [sid] [varchar] (255) NOT NULL,
    [node] [varchar] (255) NOT NULL,
    [pid] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [bosh_PRIMARY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
        [sid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
) TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY];
```

no se ejecuta el query. Aparece elsiguiente mensaje

Cannot use TEXTIMAGE_ON when a table has no text, ntext, image, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), non-FILESTREAM varbinary(max), xml or large CLR type columns.

Probe insertando solo

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[bosh] (
        [sid] [varchar] (255) NOT NULL,
        [node] [varchar] (255) NOT NULL,
        [pid] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
     CONSTRAINT [bosh_PRIMARY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
            [sid] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
    ) ON [PRIMARY];
```

en ambas no se ejecuta el query?

Comment: que error te arroja??

Comment: No se ejecuta el query?Cannot use TEXTIMAGE_ON when a table has no text, ntext, image, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), non-FILESTREAM varbinary(max), xml or large CLR type columns.

Answer (score 1):

La forma correcta es:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[bosh] (
        [sid] [varchar] (255) NOT NULL,
        [node] [varchar] (255) NOT NULL,
        [pid] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
     CONSTRAINT [bosh_PRIMARY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
            [sid] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```